# Vacuum Energy in QFT under the Light of Divergence Invariance of the Lagrangian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, harmonic-oscillator, vacuum, cosmological-constant

The divergence invariance of the Lagrangian has been exploited many times, eg., for the purposes of obtaining a symmetric energy-momentum tensor --Belinfante-like-- consistent with GR.
We know the standard Hamiltonian for the quantum harmonic oscillator,
$$
H=\frac{p^{2}}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega^{2}x^{2}
$$
leads to the problem of vacuum energy.

My observation is: If we exploited once again this divergence invariance, *seems* like we could in principle write a (hopefully better) Lagrangian.
A naive attempt (classically) would be,
$$
L=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^{2}-\frac{1}{2}m\omega^{2}x^{2}+\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{m\omega}{2}x^{2}\right)=
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^{2}-\frac{1}{2}m\omega^{2}x^{2}+m\omega x\dot{x}
$$
$$
p=m\left(\dot{x}+\omega x\right)
$$
which makes no difference as to equations of motion.
Quantum mechanically,
$$
H_{\textrm{SHO}}-\frac{1}{2}m\omega^{2}x^{2}-\frac{\omega}{2}\left(px+xp\right)
$$
This particular modification to the Lagrangian is likely to produce a Hamiltonian that's not bounded below. (Thanks to @ValterMoretti & @lux for corrections.)

An operation like this looks like it would potentially enable one to displace the energy levels of the oscillators, while preserving the (classical) equations of motion if one manages to find a proper $\frac{d}{dt}$ term. Is that a promising avenue at all?

Comment: I do not think the Hamiltonian you wrote is bounded below...

Comment: You're totally right. Thank you. My bad. I think I've got that in my notes from long time ago, when I tinkered with this. Do you see any workable modification of the derivative idea that could lead to a Hamiltonian that's bounded below? Probably an edit is in order, which I'll get around to ASAP.

Comment: Have you recalculated the conjugate momentum after introducing the new term? I'm unsure about the coefficient 1/2 in the second term of H

Comment: Yes, you're right. $p$ should be $m\left(\dot{x}+\omega x\right)$. And $H$ would change to $H_{\textrm{SHO}}-\frac{1}{2}m\omega^{2}x^{2}-\frac{\omega}{2}\left(px+xp\right)$ I will edit.

Comment: Now complete the square in p, and make a change of variables to see that you will reproduce the same quantum system (as must be the case, since you added a total derivative to L)